# Does the NRWL support the Cypress version 10.0.0?

Tags: cypress, nrwl-nx, nrwl

We are using nrwl/Cypress. The current version we are using:

- "cypress": "^9.1.0"
- "@nrwl/cypress": "14.1.7"

I would like to know if the Cypress version 10.0.0 is supported by NRWL? If it does, then how do we migrates our cypress project to the newest version 10.0.0 when using NRWL?

Answer (score 1):

https://nx.dev/cypress/v10-migration-guide

> Before continuing, make sure you have all your changes committed and have a clean working tree.
>
> You can migrate an E2E project to v10 by running the following command:
>
> `nx g @nrwl/cypress:migrate-to-cypress-10`